# IBM Watson Assistant: How to assign the correct out of two @sys-date

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

In Watson Assistant, I am using a @sys-date to fill a slot. I am using Spanish language. When I try to use the sentence "El próximo Sábado", that is "next Saturday", it recognizes two dates `(@sys-date:2019-10-12
@sys-date:2019-10-19)` and it saves`@sys-date:2019-10-12` in the slot, what is a mistake. 
How can I manage it?

Thanks

Comment: Is the saved date as expected based on the defined behavior? See https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-system-entities#system-entities-last-next

Comment: This help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57652369/1167890